# Bounded Wildcards in Java

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard, bounded-types

This is not fine

```
     List<List<? extends Number>> a;
     List<List<Integer>> b;
     a = b;
```

This is fine

```
     List<? extends Number> c;
     List<Integer> d;
     c = d;
```

How can make it compile first one?

Comment: What do you want to compile, the first option?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use this:

```
List<? extends List<? extends Number>> a;
List<List<Integer>> b;
a = b;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<? extends List<? extends Number>> a = null;
List<List<Integer>> b = null;
a = b;
```